# Problems with pyinstaller doesn´t show all things that I created

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, pyinstaller

I've been working on an app to manage a little store with Python and SQLite. For GUI I used `tkinter`. I've written 13 Python scripts to make the app work. One of them call "principal.py" which imports most of the scripts and the other scripts import other modules like `tkcalendar` or `xlwt` (to write excel sheets), etc...
This is an example from "principal.py" first lines of code

```
#===========IMPORTAR PAQUETES=============
import sqlite3
from sqlite3 import Error
import os
import sys
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import scrolledtext
from tkinter import Menu
from tkinter import messagebox as msg
import tkcalendar
from tkcalendar import *
import conexion as cnx
import proveedores
from proveedores import Proveedores
from proveedores import *
import productos
from productos import Categoria_Productos
from productos import *
import clientes
from clientes import Clientes
from clientes import *
import colaboradores
from colaboradores import Colaboradores
from colaboradores import *
import herramientas
from herramientas import Roles
from herramientas import Usuarios
from herramientas import *
import recepciondoc
from recepciondoc import Recepcion
from recepciondoc import *
import ventas
from ventas import Ventas
from ventas import *
import ingresos
from ingresos import *
import movimientos
from movimientos import *
import excel_ingresos
from excel_ingresos import *
import excel_venta
from excel_venta import *
```

[This is how my files are structured and how it works when I run the script from vscode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bdwwl.png)

But when I tried to make an exe from my little project using PyInstaller, it looks incomplete like this:
[this is how it looks like when I run the exe file from the "dist" folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O6Fzf.png)

I worked like this

1. Create the spec file with pyi-makespec principal.py
2. Re-write the principal.spec to save the database path
3. pyinstaller --windowed principal.spec

Comment: Hmmmm as far as i know, for `tkcalendar` to work you need to import `babel.numbers` too, for now try saying `pyinstaller -c principal.spec` and then do share any errors that come up in the console

Comment: I modified my spec file and add this hiddenimports=["babel.numbers"], it works fine thanks for your support..